# confusion with else block in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have confusion with my code. It is working fine in both cases but I want to know why it is correct. My main concern is for function return it supposes to be executed every time however it's not. 
Can anybody point what I am missing with the concepts?

```
    def is_empty(self):
       """
       check array is empty
       :return: true or false
       """

       if self.n != 0:
           return False
       return True
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "for function return it supposes to be executed every time however it's not"?

Comment: I mean second return statement "return True". Like method every time have to return this, however, it is not the case when if statement above it returns false. Function working as suppose to but I want to know why else statement is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Method doesn't have to execute the second return statement. If the if-statement is executed, then the first return is executed. Once that happens, the functions "returns" - which means that control goes back to the caller of the method. Anything that is there after this return, will not be executed.

Comment: @rdas great, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

So first of all, your code as pasted will not run, because your statements are on the same level as your function declaration. Probably this is just a copy-and-paste error.

Also, you don't need an `else` *or* an `if`. Simply write `return self.n == 0`. It returns a boolean directly.

Comment: yeah, it is due to copy past, otherwise, it working fine. please can you explain why it is working correctly?